# getting value to use as an increment in a dataset from a datagrid

Tags: vb.net

Basically i need to get a value out from a datagrid which is a text to use as an increment when referring to a dataset. I have got other points in my prog. where i use a text and it works.

```
 inc = DGHomework.Item("QuizID", DGHomework.CurrentRow.Index).ToString


    'retriveing questions and asnwers from the database

    Q1 = datasetQuiz.Tables("quizdetails").Rows(inc).Item(7)
    A1 = datasetQuiz.Tables("quizdetails").Rows(inc).Item(8)
    Q2 = datasetQuiz.Tables("quizdetails").Rows(inc).Item(9)
```

It is saying that the value cannot be converted to an integer where i have the inc =

Comment: Well what's the value, it surely isn't a number... Also `ToString` you can't do if your variable is an integer. probably is your problem. Remove that and turn **Option Strict On**

Comment: There's other changes that could be made as well but isn't the culprit in this case...

Comment: how do i turn option strict on and what does it do?

Comment: Declare it at top of class or at project level... Do a Google search if you want to know...

Answer (score -1):

```
inc = DGHomework.Item("QuizID", DGHomework.CurrentRow.Index).ToString
```

is your problem. Have a look at where *inc* is declared. Either you should declare is as an Integer, or you should declare another variable as an integer .. as below ..if you need inc to be a string elsewhere

```
inc = DGHomework.Item("QuizID", DGHomework.CurrentRow.Index).ToString


'retriveing questions and asnwers from the database
dim index as integer=DGHomework.Item("QuizID", DGHomework.CurrentRow.Index)
Q1 = datasetQuiz.Tables("quizdetails").Rows(index).Item(7)
A1 = datasetQuiz.Tables("quizdetails").Rows(index).Item(8)
Q2 = datasetQuiz.Tables("quizdetails").Rows(index).Item(9)
```

Alternatively you could use

```
inc = DGHomework.Item("QuizID", DGHomework.CurrentRow.Index).ToString


'retriveing questions and asnwers from the database

Q1 = datasetQuiz.Tables("quizdetails").Rows(val(inc)).Item(7)
A1 = datasetQuiz.Tables("quizdetails").Rows(val(inc)).Item(8)
Q2 = datasetQuiz.Tables("quizdetails").Rows(val(inc)).Item(9)
```